# Is there a bibtex style that sorts references according to publication type?

Tags: bibtex, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting the bibliography by entry type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/sorting-the-bibliography-by-entry-type)

I am updating my CV and I was wondering if there exists a way to sort publications according to their type (articles, inproceedings, and so on..).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: How to achieve this with bibLaTeX is described in the following Q-A: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6959/19384

Comment: There's also a "traditional BibTeX" answer in the linked question, so I'm voting to close this one.