# How do I make my bibliography according to harvard-style (author-year, alphabetical by sourcetype...) in Lyx?

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, harvard-style

I am writing my master thesis using Lyx and I don't know how it would be the best way to set up my bibliography due to the requirements by the university. The Bibliography has to be arranged alphabetically making subsections for each source type and has to use the Harvard Referencing System including the citation style (author,year). As I advance writing I have tried out to find the best way, but I have struggled to find out how it would be the best way. How would you guys do it and what would I have to do to be able to implement it. I am building up my .bib file and try to use natbib but it does not work. I appreciate any suggestions, as it is my first time using Lyx and I wrote my Diploma thesis in physics about 8 years ago.

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer now, but you can do this with `biblatex` I think. See http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex for how to use `biblatex` in LyX, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/sorting-the-bibliography-by-entry-type for the problem of sorting by type. You also want `style=authoryear` in the options to `biblatex`.

Comment: There are plenty of solutions to do what you want on the web (and on SE). And if you are stuck on a certain point, go back to us.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this with `biblatex`, which is a quite new LaTeX package for dealing with bibliographies. As LyX hasn't built in support for this in the GUI yet, there is some initial setup required. The information in this answer comes from two sources:

1. The LyX wiki: http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex
2. [Sorting the bibliography by entry type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/sorting-the-bibliography-by-entry-type)

## Setting up LyX for `biblatex`

You have to install a `biblatex` module, which is can be downloaded at http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/BibTeX/biblatex.module Place the `biblatex.module` file in the *layouts* folder in the LyX user directory, the location of which is listed in Help --> About LyX. Reconfigure and restart LyX.

## Change document settings

Go to Document --> Settings, and do the following:

1. Under **Modules**, add the *Biblatex-citation-styles* module.
2. Under **Bibliography**, change

   1. Processor to *biber*
   2. Citation to *Natbib*, and Natbib style to *Author-year*

   [image]
3. Under **LaTeX Preamble**, add the following:

   ```
   \usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{path/to/your/bibfile.bib}
   ```

   of course changing the path to the bib-file. I think you need the complete path, and the file ending must be included.

## In the document

To be able to use the LyX GUI to add citations, you have to trick LyX to search that file by first adding a LyX Note with Insert --> Note --> LyX Note, and then do Insert --> List/ToC --> BibTeX bibliography with the cursor inside the note.

Add an unnumbered (or numbered, depending on requirements) chapter (or section, if you're using an article-class) heading, called *Bibliography* or *References*, or whatever you like. Then you have to add something like

```
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books},heading=subbibliography]    
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles},heading=subbibliography]    
\printbibliography[nottype=book,nottype=article,title={Miscellaneous},heading=subbibliography]
```

in an ERT (Insert --> TeX Code, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) where you want to print the reference lists. Note the `type=<reference type>`, which defines that the reference list printed there has only one type of source, and the `title=Something` that changes the heading of the reference list. You have to add one `\printbibliography` for each type of source.

`heading=subbibliography` causes the heading to be typeset with a heading that is one level below the highest level. That is, section for book or report classes (where chapter is the highest), or subsection for article classes (where section is the highest).

In the last one `nottype` is used instead, which prints everything that does not have the specified entry type. Note there is one such for article, one for book.

Image example. Here I added three citations from `biblatex-examples.bib`, one book, one article, and one something else:

[image]