# Customizing Bibliography with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx

Using LyX. I made the conversion from `bibtex` to `biblatex` today, as I think it will help get a quick response, and be better for the long-term. I am trying to take the `apa` format and tweak a few things. I could use some help.

This is my preamble:

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{C:~/refs.bib}
```

I want the journal, book, etc to be italicized AND bolded.

Comment: LyX doesn't (yet) have built in support for `biblatex`, you need to select author-year style in the document settings, and some other stuff. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146159/how-do-i-make-my-bibliography-according-to-harvard-style-author-year-alphabeti/148410#148410

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This  handles everything besides the bolded names in the references

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to make that the main focus. (It is generally best to have on specific issue per question anyway, you have two somewhat different questions in your post.) The (very) general answer to customizing `biblatex` styles is http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/586, but you can perhaps use and modify the example found under **Formatting of fields (and of citation postnotes)**.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That link was very helpful, but I am just trying to add the bolding to this style and not globally. Every attempt thus far has caused LyX to crash.

Comment: What do you mean by 'globally'?  When you load a biblatex style, it is used 'globally' in that document, and thus any changes you make would be applied 'globally' to a document that uses it....  It is also difficult to provide advice on how to make 'etc.' be anything: you must list precisely which fields for which entry types need to be put in bold and italics -- which is likely goingn to require the use of `\DeclareFieldFormat[<entry type>]{<format>}{<code>}` where 'entry type' would be something like 'article', 'format' is 'journaltitle', and 'code' is `\textbf{\emph{#1}}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareFieldFormat` to modify how different fields are printed. The general syntax is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[<entry type>]{<field>}{<formatting commands>}
```

`<entry type>` can be a single entry type, e.g. `article`, or a comma separated list of entry types, e.g. `article,book`. `<field>` is the field you want to change, e.g. `title`. `<formatting commands>` defines how the field should be printed, with `#1` representing the field contents.

Hence, to make the title of the journal for articles, and book titles, bold and italic, you could add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article]
  {journaltitle}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [book]
  {title}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
```

to the LaTeX preamble, after `\usepackage{biblatex}`.  If you want quotation marks, use `\mkbibquote{#1}`. `biblatex` also has a bunch of commands for controlling punctuation, see section 4.7.3 *Adding punctuation* of the manual.

Comment: This is close, however, I wanted the journal bolded and italicized for articles and not the title. However, for books, I want the title. I tried editing your code as follows, but it did not work for the article. `\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article]
  {journal}{\mkbibquote{\textbf{\textit{#1\isdot}}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [book]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{\textbf{\textit{#1\isdot}}}}`

Comment: Also, can the code be modified to remove the quotation marks around the book title?

Comment: Try journaltitle in place of journal in the first line. Then remove the \mkbibquote{} in the second line.

Comment: This code will get to the desired result, `\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article]
  {journaltitle}{\textbf{\textit{#1\isdot}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [book]
  {title}{\textbf{\textit{#1\isdot}}}`

Comment: @ChrisJ Sorry, I obviously misunderstood you. (I'll update my answer based on your comments a bit later.)