# How do you change the Editor field in Bibliography using Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

**EDIT**: I've revised this to be a single Q&A following @moewe's advice.

In my bibliography how do I get the "editor" field to be abbreviated, written in lowercase, and in parentheses? I need it to be like so:

> (ed. by A. Poole).

rather than like

> Ed. by A. Poole

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames = 2,mincitenames = 1,maxbibnames = 99,minbibnames = 1,dashed = false,firstinits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}  
% !BIB TS-program = biber     
%^ line above is necessary to tell TeXShop to use Biblatex rathern than traditional BibTex.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % utf8 support       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % code for pdf file  % w/out these two lines, I get the warning, "WARN - The entry '_______' has characters which cannot be encoded in 'ascii'. Recoding problematic characters into macros.

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}
@incollection{johnson2000brown,
Location = {Ithaca, NY},                                 % Edit (Changed)
Publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology},                % Edit (Changed)
Author = {Johnson, Richard E. and Hendricks, P. and Pattie, D. L. and Hunter, K. B.},
Editor = {Poole, A.},
Booktitle = {The birds of North America online},
Title = {Brown-capped rosy-finch (\textit{{Leucosticte} australis})},
url = {http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536},
Year = {2000}} 
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}

%% ===== Diversity and Distributions Bibliography Style===================
% Remove space between First and Middle Initials.  % Added
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\,}
% Remove the "In" prior to item.                   % Added
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}     
% Have "Available at:" written prior to URL and "accessed" date written (for other citations not in this particular example).       % Added
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%          
urlseen = {accessed}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {accessed},
url = {Available at:}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}}



%Remove any punctuation after the Year in parentheses.
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

% Add comma after journal title
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\addcomma}}

% Always get last name in bibliography prior to first name being printed.
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 

% Changes "and" to "&" in Bibliography.
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} 

% Removes quotations around the following titles.        
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,collection,incollection,manual,
misc,periodical,proceedings,report,thesis,software,unpublished]
{title}{#1} 

% removes pages abbreviation (pp)
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}

% bolds journal volume   --> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153597/customizing-bibliography-with-biblatex
\DeclareFieldFormat  
[article]
{volume}{\textbf{#1}}  

% Prevent Italics for booktitle in these data types 
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,book,manual,misc,software,unpublished]
{booktitle}{#1}

% removes number of article issue from bibliography ---> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex    
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}} 

%% =================================================
\begin{document}

Test cite \parencite{johnson2000brown}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This results with the following bibliography items:

> Johnson, R.E., Hendricks, P., Pattie, D.L. & Hunter, K.B. (2000) Brown-capped   rosy-finch (*Leucosticte australis*). *The birds of North America online*. Ed. by A. Poole. Ithaca, NY: Cornell Lab of Ornithology. Available at: **http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536**.

I would like the items to be like this:

> Johnson, R.E., Hendricks, P., Pattie, D.L. & Hunter, K.B. (2000) Brown-capped rosy-finch (*Leucosticte australis*). *The birds of North America online* (ed. by A. Poole). Ithaca, NY: Cornell Lab of Ornithology. Available at:   http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536.

Comment: Please, please only ask one question at a time. Many parts of your question have been answered elsewhere on this site. Also please make your MWE truly minimal. The `caption`, `geometry` packages etc. have no bearing on the bibliography. (And make sure the code uses proper mark-up, it looks somewhat torn apart now.)

Comment: For (Cite 1) ad 1 see [biblatex: Putting thin spaces between initials](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10203/35864): `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{}`. ad 2: [Suppress “In:” biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864). For 3 I cannot find a duplicate immediately: You could extract this question as fitted for the Q&A format and ask it separately. Ad 4 can be taken care of like [Changing predefined words in a biblatex bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202192/35864). Ad 5 is certainly possible (maybe slightly ugly), cannot find a duplicate now you could extract that one, too

Comment: For cite 2, ad 1 should be possible modifying  the `url+urldate` macro, could be combined into a new question with ad 5 of cite 1 (both are URL-related). Ad 2 somehow contradicts ad 4 in cite 1. How do you propose to distinguish when to say what?

Comment: Note that you should not say `addendum = {(accessed 01 September 2013)},`, but give the access date in the `urldate` field like `urldate = {2013-09-01},` `biblatex` will take care of all the formatting necessary (after you nudge it a bit). Also the first name initials in the `.bib` file would normally contain a full stop to signify we deal with initials here `Editor = {Poole, A.},` (though you might dispute that that is necessary). `Address = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology, Ithaca, NY},` seems a bit fishy, maybe `publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology}, location ={Ithaca, NY},` is better.

Comment: @moewe, I've changed my question and incorporated many of your answers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the question can be properly answered, and you even got a nice answer to the other question already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do what you want. We just need to tweak the macro `byeditor+others` a bit to include parentheses if necessary. Fortunately, `\setunit` and `\printunit` can be used to get this.

```
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \setunit{\space(}% <---- this is new ...
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \printunit*{)\newunitpunct}}% <---- and this
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames = 2,mincitenames = 1,maxbibnames = 99,minbibnames = 1,dashed = false,firstinits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}  
% !BIB TS-program = biber     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{johnson2000brown,
Location = {Ithaca, NY},                                 % Edit (Changed)
Publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology},                % Edit (Changed)
Author = {Johnson, Richard E. and Hendricks, P. and Pattie, D. L. and Hunter, K. B.},
Editor = {Poole, A.},
Booktitle = {The birds of North America online},
Title = {Brown-capped rosy-finch (\textit{{Leucosticte} australis})},
url = {http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536},
Year = {2000}} 

@incollection{johnson2000brown1,
Location = {Ithaca, NY},                                 % Edit (Changed)
Publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology},                % Edit (Changed)
Author = {Johnson, Richard E. and Hendricks, P. and Pattie, D. L. and Hunter, K. B.},
Booktitle = {The birds of North America online},
Title = {Brown-capped rosy-finch (\textit{{Leucosticte} australis})},
url = {http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536},
Year = {2000}} 

@incollection{johnson2000brown2,
translator = {Poole, A.},
Location = {Ithaca, NY},                                 % Edit (Changed)
Publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology},                % Edit (Changed)
Author = {Johnson, Richard E. and Hendricks, P. and Pattie, D. L. and Hunter, K. B.},
Booktitle = {The birds of North America online},
Title = {Brown-capped rosy-finch (\textit{{Leucosticte} australis})},
url = {http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536},
Year = {2000}} 
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\,}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}     
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%          
urlseen = {accessed}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {accessed},
url = {Available at:}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\addcomma}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} 

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,collection,incollection,manual,
misc,periodical,proceedings,report,thesis,software,unpublished]
{title}{#1} 

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat  
[article]
{volume}{\textbf{#1}}  

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,book,manual,misc,software,unpublished]
{booktitle}{#1}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}} 


\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \setunit{\space(}%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \printunit*{)\newunitpunct}}

\begin{document}
Test cite \parencite{johnson2000brown,johnson2000brown1,johnson2000brown2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate that you marked where you inserted the parentheses. Your example is helpful for learning how the code works!

Answer (score 0):

I would just modify one thing in the previous answer, but it requires some explanation so I cannot just edit Moewe's post, which futhermore is perfect relatively to the `biblatex` options specified in the original post.

This is for compatibility with `ext-authoryear`'s `innamebeforetitle` option, **for those who still want *(ed(s). by)* for journal editors, especially if you don't like the *in* before journal title** (`articlein` option set to *false*).

The problem is that the manually added closing parenthese may appear as a nuisance in case the editor is defined but has already been printed.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ext-authoryear,innamebeforetitle=true,articlein=false,natbib=true]{biblatex} % "ext-authoryear" features the convenient "innamebeforetitle" option

\nocite{*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}} % (ed(s).)
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} % No comma before (ed.)
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space} % Comma after Editor Name(s).


     \begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
    @incollection{johnson2000brown,
     Location = {Ithaca, NY},                                
     Publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology},               
     Author = {Johnson, Richard E. and Hendricks, P. and Pattie, D. L. and Hunter, K. B.},
     Editor = {Poole, A.},
     Booktitle = {The birds of North America online},
     Title = {Brown-capped rosy-finch (\textit{{Leucosticte} australis})},
     url = {http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536},
     Year = {2000}}
    
    @inproceedings{VILDES,
     Author    = {Villoing, Florence and Desmets, Marianne},
     Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar},
     Date      = {2009},
     Title     = {French {VN} Lexemes: Morphological Compounding in {HPSG}},
     Editor    = {Müller, Stefan},
     Location  = {Stanford},
     Publisher = {CSLI},
     Pages = {89--109},
     Venue     = {Georg-August-Universität, Göttingen}}
      
    @Article{RAPLEV92,
     Author       = {Rappaport Hovav, Malka and Levin, Beth},
     Year         = {1992},
     Journaltitle = {Syntax and Semantics},
     Title        = {\textit{-er} Nominals: Implications for the Theory of Argument Structure},
     Editor       = {Stowell, Tim and Wehrli, Eric},
     Issuetitle   = {Syntax and the Lexicon},
     Pages        = {127--153},
     Volume       = {26}}
    \end{filecontents*}
 \addbibresource{biblio.bib}
  
  
   \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
        \setunit{\space(}%
        \ifnameundef{editor}
          {}
          {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
           \clearname{editor}%
           \newunit}%
        \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
        \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
        \printunit*{)\newunitpunct}}%


\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Now look at the result (I've circled in red the parasitic closing parenthese):

[image]

My humble contribution is only to suggest we had better use `\printtext[parens]{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ext-authoryear,innamebeforetitle=true,articlein=false,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\nocite{*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}} % (ed(s).)
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} % No comma before (ed.)
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space} % Comma after Editor Name(s).


    \begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
    @incollection{johnson2000brown,
     Location = {Ithaca, NY},                                
     Publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology},               
     Author = {Johnson, Richard E. and Hendricks, P. and Pattie, D. L. and Hunter, K. B.},
     Editor = {Poole, A.},
     Booktitle = {The birds of North America online},
     Title = {Brown-capped rosy-finch (\textit{{Leucosticte} australis})},
     url = {http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536},
     Year = {2000}}
    
    @inproceedings{VILDES,
     Author    = {Villoing, Florence and Desmets, Marianne},
     Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar},
     Date      = {2009},
     Title     = {French {VN} Lexemes: Morphological Compounding in {HPSG}},
     Editor    = {Müller, Stefan},
     Location  = {Stanford},
     Publisher = {CSLI},
     Pages = {89--109},
     Venue     = {Georg-August-Universität, Göttingen}}
      
    @Article{RAPLEV92,
     Author       = {Rappaport Hovav, Malka and Levin, Beth},
     Year         = {1992},
     Journaltitle = {Syntax and Semantics},
     Title        = {\textit{-er} Nominals: Implications for the Theory of Argument Structure},
     Editor       = {Stowell, Tim and Wehrli, Eric},
     Issuetitle   = {Syntax and the Lexicon},
     Pages        = {127--153},
     Volume       = {26}}
    \end{filecontents*}
 \addbibresource{biblio.bib}

  
   \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
      \setunit{\space}%  I have removed the opening parenthese.
      \ifnameundef{editor}
          {}
          {\printtext[parens] % This is for enclosing the desired string between parentheses.
             {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
                \clearname{editor}%
                \newunit}%
              \usebibmacro{byeditorx}} % Closing curly bracket must be put here, not above, or only “ed. by” will be enclosed.
           \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
           \newunitpunct} % Now, \newunit is removed, and no parasitic parenthese is printed.


\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

Now we can check that everything will remain fine with the original settings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\nocite{*}

    \begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
    @incollection{johnson2000brown,
     Location = {Ithaca, NY},                                
     Publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology},               
     Author = {Johnson, Richard E. and Hendricks, P. and Pattie, D. L. and Hunter, K. B.},
     Editor = {Poole, A.},
     Booktitle = {The birds of North America online},
     Title = {Brown-capped rosy-finch (\textit{{Leucosticte} australis})},
     url = {http://bna.birds.cornell.edu/bna/species/536},
     Year = {2000}}
    
    @inproceedings{VILDES,
     Author    = {Villoing, Florence and Desmets, Marianne},
     Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar},
     Date      = {2009},
     Title     = {French {VN} Lexemes: Morphological Compounding in {HPSG}},
     Editor    = {Müller, Stefan},
     Location  = {Stanford},
     Publisher = {CSLI},
     Pages = {89--109},
     Venue     = {Georg-August-Universität, Göttingen}}
      
    @Article{RAPLEV92,
     Author       = {Rappaport Hovav, Malka and Levin, Beth},
     Year         = {1992},
     Journaltitle = {Syntax and Semantics},
     Title        = {\textit{-er} Nominals: Implications for the Theory of Argument Structure},
     Editor       = {Stowell, Tim and Wehrli, Eric},
     Issuetitle   = {Syntax and the Lexicon},
     Pages        = {127--153},
     Volume       = {26}}
    \end{filecontents*}
 \addbibresource{biblio.bib}

  
    \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
      \setunit{\space}%  I have removed the opening parenthese.
      \ifnameundef{editor}
          {}
          {\printtext[parens] % This is for enclosing the desired string between parentheses.
             {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
                \clearname{editor}%
                \newunit}%
              \usebibmacro{byeditorx}} % Closing curly bracket must be put here, not above, or only “ed. by” will be enclosed.
           \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
           \newunitpunct} % Now, \newunit is removed, and no parasitic parenthese is printed.


\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As we can see, everything is fine.