# Bibliographies by chapter using bibtopic on classicthesis LyX port

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, chapters, classicthesis

I need help with bibliographies by chapter using bibtopic with classicthesis (v4.1 LyX) with LyX (v2.0.2) under Ubuntu Linux (or a better option). I need bibliographies at the end of each chapter (as a section) in my thesis document. I read in the classicthesis example documentation (publications) that I can use bibtopic, multibib or some similar package to get multiple bibliographies. I found bibtopic as an easy option because this package doesn't requires new command definitions and also because LyX has native integration with it. I tried to use this package in my document but I have not had success.

Here are the steps I followed to try to get what I need (I have attached a [zipped folder](http://goo.gl/cq6owv) with the LyX files in order to reproduce the results):

1. I have one bib file for each chapter to contain the corresponding references (chap_01.bib and chap_02.bib)
2. I configured each chapter document (chap_01.lyx and chap_01.lyx, child documents) with sectioned bibliography. Then I inserted the bibliography through LyX (Insert, List/TOC, BibTeX Bibliography) at the end of each chapter file, taking care referencing the corresponding bib file. Also I inserted some ERT surrounding the bibliography entry, as it is in the Bibliography.lyx file that come with classicthesis LyX port, to get the bibliography section title in the TOC.
3. I configured the bibliography of my master document (ClassicThesis.lyx) with default parameters, i.e. with not sectioned bibliography because otherwise, I obtain the bibtopic error message: "Load bibtopic after hyperref when using the 'backref'".

Although I can compile and generate the pdf file with the above configuration, the cites appear as [? ] and the bibliography section (references) doesn't appear in the document.

Also, I have tried to use the bibtopic pakcage using btUnit and btSect  (through ERT) along the documents as described in the bibtopic documentation but I had not success.

**Example [LyX files](http://goo.gl/cq6owv)**

I would appreciate any help in getting what I need either using this package or  better option.

Thanks,

Héctor

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I haven't looked at your files (yet), I'll just mention that it is very easy to make per-chapter bibliographies with `biblatex` and `biber`, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87414. There is a little bit of work required to use `biblatex` with LyX though, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146159/

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn T. for you reply. With the posts suggested, I managed to configure my LyX to obtain bibliographies per chapter through `biblatex`, `biber` and some ERT in my documents. This package is cool and very configurable. Thanks again.

Comment: @hspitia Nice, clear question. If you have the time it would be great if you could answer your own question with detailed steps. Some users have trouble setting up LyX with biblatex so a clear example (your answer) would be nice to have for us to refer them to.