# LyX add iso 690 numeric citation style

Tags: lyx, citing

how can i add the citation style "iso 690 numeric" to a lyx document?
ive installed the package for miktex but it didnt help
i've read that i need some kind of a ".bst" file for that, but there is none in the package.

since the mailing lists for lyx are currently unavaible, ive desided to ask here.

Comment: Are you referring to https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-iso690? That is a package for `biblatex`, a more modern package for bibliographies than the standard BibTeX system that uses `.bst` files. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299312/biblatex-biber-and-lyx-how-to-resolve-bibliographystyle-error/299318#299318 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146159/how-do-i-make-my-bibliography-according-to-harvard-style-author-year-alphabeti/148410#148410 for some instructions for using `biblatex` with LyX. Use `style=iso-numeric` in the `biblatex` options.

Comment: Also note that LyX 2.3.0 will have built-in support for `biblatex` (https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX23#biblatex). 2.3.0rc1 will hopefully be announced early next week, so the final release is not too far away.

Comment: thanks for answers, i think i got it to work now, but i have 1 more little problem... i am from germany and ofc. the bibliography should be in german, which it is, but the dates are in english format, it should say: [21. July 2015] but it says [2015-07-21] instead, which is a nogo. Can you tell me something about that or should i contact the package author?

Comment: The manual says something about having to specify `langid={german}` in the entry in the `.bib` file. I did try that, but it didn't seem to have any effect on e.g. a `urldate`. It might not be implemented, you could post an issue at https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/issues